# Fix JetBrains IDE graphic bug where menu windows are displayed across multiple monitors

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Many IDEs from JetBrains have this annoying graphic bug (IntelliJ & PyCharm, and probably WebStorm / PhpStorm too): while on dual screens, when you open menu or right click somewhere, if it's close to the edge of the screen, and there is another monitor next to it, the window is displayed across both screens and is very poorly readable.

[image]

I have been dealing with that issue forever but I forgot how to fix it. I always struggle to find the answer and I can't find it again this time, so I'm creating this question for posterity. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Might be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218116

Comment: @Koyasha is it just me or this returns a 404? (I am logged in with my jetbrains account, I can see other IDEA issues but not this one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [IDEA-157583](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157583) issue. Unfortunately there is no known reliable workaround. The issue has some workarounds that help some users e.g. see [one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157583#focus=Comments-27-4206894.0-0), [two](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157583#focus=Comments-27-4288721.0-0), [three](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-157583#focus=Comments-27-4109670.0-0). See also other comments in that thread or in linked issues.